# Excel VBA - sheet being protected too quickly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that loops through cells whose values have been changed and amends the values of other cells in the same row.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = false
    ' Unprotect the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect("password")

    Set newRange = Range("K:K")

    If Not Application.Intersect(newRange, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell in Target.Cells       
            ' Change the values of cells in the same row
            r = cell.Row

            Cells(r, 2).Value = "New Value"
            Cells(r, 3).Value = "New Value"   ' Debug highlights this line
            Cells(r, 4).Value = "New Value"
            Cells(r, 5).Value = "New Value"

        Next


    End If

    ' Reprotect the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Without unprotecting/reprotecting the sheet the macro works fine, but when added it generates a Runtime Error `Application-Defined or Object-Defined error`, but not before changing the first cell value `Cells(r, 2).Value = "New Value"`.

I can only assume that this is because the sheet is unprotected at the start and the first cell value change completes before the sheet is then locked (perhaps running in a separate thread to the For loop?). The macro then errors at the following line because it is trying to make a change to a protected sheet.

How can I fix this and prevent the sheet from locking too quickly?

Comment: first line: "ByVal Target As Row" should be "ByVal Target As Range"

Comment: Thanks, amended the question

Comment: Are you really assigning `"New Value"`? Can you reproduce the problem with the exact code as you have given it in your question? (except for the password of course)

Comment: The value being assigned isn't relevant. If I assign `"New Value"`, it would still shows the same error. This has been sorted now anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing cells with the event macro.

You must:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

before the `For` loop and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

after the `For` loop.

Comment: Thank you, spot on